# How to use a query string to load a certain image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I understand correctly I can use a query string and parse it to load certain info. How would I use that to load a certain image?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYXexG

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="panel">
    <img id="largeImage" src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_01_large.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="thumbs">
        <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
        <img src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_02_thumb.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

For example, there are two pictures here with thumbs underneath to load a larger image. How can I do something like http://www.example.com/?image=1 to preselect thumb 1 and http://www.example.com/?image=2 to preselect thumb 2?

I see that a query string something like this:

```
<?php
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['email']; 
?>
```

But I don't know how to connect that with the images.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way would be:

```
<img id="largeImage" src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_<?php echo $_GET['image'] ?: '01'; ?>_large.jpg" />
```

Note that you should use `?image=01` instead of `?image=1`.

Otherwise you should do something like:

```
<?php 
     echo $_GET['image'] 
          ? 
          ( 
               $_GET['image'] < 10 
               ? '0'.$_GET['image'] 
               : $_GET['image'] 
          ) 
          : '01';
?>
```

It can be used within `#largeImage` like this:

```
<img id="largeImage" src="http://robgolbeck.com/demos/image-swap/image_<?php echo $_GET['image'] ? ( $_GET['image'] < 10 ? '0'.$_GET['image'] : $_GET['image'] ) : '01'; ?>_large.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! Cool! I have a feeling that is slows down the web page though, is that possible (or just a coincidence)?

Comment: The PHP code should not take that long. So I guess its just a coincidence. But you could measure that by logging some sort of micro timing before/after.